# How to check row value is empty in DataRow in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, datarow

I'm reading Excel values by using `OleDbConnection()` and saving the values in mysql.

In the Excel file, if some cell value is empty, it shows error while adding to database.

So I want to validate each value before assigning. How can I do that?

For example, for the line:

```
colBasic = row[10].ToString();
```

if this `row[10]` is empty then colBasic should be zero.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
            string path = "C:\\Pay.xls";
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

            if (File.Exists(path) == true)
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = '" + path + "'" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";
                conn.Open();

                string ex_id = "";
                string colName = "";
                string colEmpID = "";
                string colBasic = "0";
                string colHRA = "0";
                string colConveyance = "0";

                try
                {
                    OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                    OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
                    int nFields = odr.FieldCount;

                    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
                    dtable.Load(odr);
                    if (dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dtable.Rows[0];

                        if (GlobalCS.OpenConnection() == true)
                        {                            
                                for (int i = 5; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    row = dtable.Rows[i];
                                    ex_id = row[0].ToString();
                                    colEmpID = row[2].ToString();
                                    colName = row[1].ToString();
                                    colBasic = row[10].ToString();
                                    colHRA = row[11].ToString();
                                    colConveyance = row[12].ToString();                                    

                                    if (colName != "")
                                    {


                                            sQuery = "insert into salary (EmployeeID,EmployeeName,Basics,DA,HRA,Conveyance,) values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f)";
                                                                                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sQuery, GlobalCS.objMyCon);
                                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", colEmpID);
                                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", colName);
                                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("c", colBasic);
                                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", '0');
                                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("e", colHRA);
                                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f", colConveyance);   
rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 } //close of if(colName!=0)
} //close of for loop

                        }  // close of if(GlobalCS.Openconnection())
                    }  // close of if(dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
                    GlobalCS.CloseConnection();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string display = ex.Message;
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);

                    GlobalCS.CloseConnection();                    
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            else  
            {
                string display = "Payslip.xls file not found";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);

                GlobalCS.CloseConnection();              
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Use the [Ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx): `colBasic = row[10] != null ? row[10].ToString() : "0";`

Comment: No..still it gets as empty.when i see it in watch window ,row[10] shows as {}.

Comment: `colBasic = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[10]) ? row[10].ToString() : "0";`

Comment: It works. Just add ToString() in condition.colBasic = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[10].ToString()) ? row[10].ToString() : "0";

Comment: no need of toString in isnullorempty call, doing it will cause null reference exception, though whenever it is null. Prety bad approach, markpsmith answer is much better here. However ugly is the original code ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).keydown(function (event) {
      if (event.ctrlKey == true && (event.which == '107' || event.which == '109' || event.which == '187' || event.which == '189'))
       {
           event.preventDefault();
       }
   });
   });

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
        string path = "C:\\Pay.xls";
        string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

        if (File.Exists(path) == true)
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = '" + path + "'" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";
            conn.Open();

            string ex_id = "";
            string colName = "";
            string colEmpID = "";
            string colBasic = "0";
            string colHRA = "0";
            string colConveyance = "0";

            try
            {
                OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
                int nFields = odr.FieldCount;

                DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
                dtable.Load(odr);
                if (dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataRow row = dtable.Rows[0];

                    if (GlobalCS.OpenConnection() == true)
                    {                            
                            for (int i = 5; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                row = dtable.Rows[i];
                                ex_id = row[0].ToString();
                                colEmpID = row[2].ToString();
                                colName = row[1].ToString();
                                colBasic = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[10].ToString()) ? row[10].ToString() : "0";
                                colHRA = row[11].ToString();
                                colConveyance = row[12].ToString();                                    

                                if (colName != "")
                                {


                                        sQuery = "insert into salary (EmployeeID,EmployeeName,Basics,DA,HRA,Conveyance,) values(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f)";
                                                                                    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sQuery, GlobalCS.objMyCon);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", colEmpID);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", colName);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("c", colBasic);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", '0');
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("e", colHRA);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f", colConveyance);   
                                        rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                } //close of if(colName!=0)
                    } //close of for loop

                    }  // close of if(GlobalCS.Openconnection())
                }  // close of if(dtable.Rows.Count > 0)
                GlobalCS.CloseConnection();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string display = ex.Message;
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);

                GlobalCS.CloseConnection();                    
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        else  
        {
            string display = "Payslip.xls file not found";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);

            GlobalCS.CloseConnection();              
            conn.Close();
        }
```

This is the line you should change as per ur example

```
colBasic = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[10].ToString()) ? row[10].ToString() : "0";
```

Comment: !string.IsNullOrEmpty((row[10].ToString()) will throw null reference exception whenever row[10] is null (even if not possible it doesnt look good, especially given that it is not necessary) ;)